# PyQt: Get QTableWidget cell-widget row/column values

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have a `QTablWidget` with the following properties:

```
        mytable.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        mytable.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        mytable.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QTableWidget.SingleSelection)
        mytable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        mytable.verticalHeader().hide()
```

On each row of my table, I have a `QPushButton` set at a `CellWidget` like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get the `Row number` of table that the `QPushButton` is in once user press on any of the button?

For example, if user click on the `QPushButton` on the `row 2` of the table, it returns a value of 2.

**EDIT 2**

According to one of the answer, i have updated the code to this: but  I am still not getting anything. Where have i gone wrong? I tried to print out the output of `self.table.itemAt(button.pos())` and i am getting `None` .

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        data1 = ['orange','apple','banana','lemon']
        data2 = ['3','4','5.5','2']

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for i in range(4):
            item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data1[i])
            self.table.setItem(i,0,item1)
            item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data2[i])
            self.table.setItem(i,1,item2)
            self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST')
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
            self.table.setCellWidget(i,2,self.button)

    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        item = self.table.itemAt(button.pos())
        if item is not None:
            print (item.row(),item.column())


def Main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get a reference to the button that was clicked, then the [indexAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) method can be used to get the corresponding model-index:

```
button.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
...        

def handleButtonClicked(self):
    button = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
    # or button = self.sender()
    index = self.table.indexAt(button.pos())
    if index.isValid():
        print(index.row(), index.column())
```

The reason why the second example in the question returns `None` with [itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemAt) is because a QTableWidgetItem wasn't set for the cell the button occupies. By contrast, the `indexAt` method will always return a model-index (which will only be invalid for coordinates in empty areas of the view).